# Can retrieve data with $.getJSON but not $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from the cloudmade routing API service. I can do it fine using $.getJSON with the following code:

```
<button id="getJSON">Get JSON</button>


$(function () {

    $("#getJSON").click(function () {

        $.getJSON("http://routes.cloudmade.com/c6f2762bfe00414f822a9dec443569f5/api/0.3/51.500,0.100,51.500,0.1001/car.js?callback=?", function (data) {
            var test = data.route_geometry;
            alert(test);
        });
    });
});
```

Also see http://jsfiddle.net/V3qgZ/72/

When I try to do the same request using $.ajax, I cannot retrieve the data, but I'm not sure where my error is. The reason I want to use $.ajax is because $.getJSON is asynchronous, where as $.ajax can be set to 'async: false'. The code for the $.ajax request is here:

```
<button id="getJSON">Get JSON</button>


$(function () {
$("#getJSON").click(function () {
    var url = "http://routes.cloudmade.com/c6f2762bfe00414f822a9dec443569f5/api/0.3/51.500,0.100,51.500,0.1001/car.js";
    $.ajax({
        async: false;
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            test = data.route_geometry;
            alert(test);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Also at http://jsfiddle.net/FhfVW/1/

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Dude, `async:false` is **the root of all evil**!

Comment: Why exactly? Unfortunately I don't seem to have a choice!

Comment: Because it blocks your entire page, no JavaScript will work while you load the data. And in some really bad cases (like old IE) it will block your entire browser (including other tabs). You always have a choice, 99.999% of JavaScript scripts is written asynchronously.

Comment: ...unless your boss is forcing you to use `async:false`. In that case: find new job. ;)

Comment: @NickF: Not only *do* you have a choice, but in fact, your `async: false` is being actively ignored by jQuery, because you've said `dataType: "jsonp"`. JSONP is **always** asynchronous (`async: true`), by its nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error `async: false` remove `;` and add `,`

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/FhfVW/2/

Comment: And of course, `async: false` is invalid for JSONP anyway. JSONP is *always* asynchronous. (AND `async: false` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of jQuery.)

Comment: Oh gosh...embarrassingly simple, thankyou! Sometimes these things require a second set of eyes!

Comment: @NickF: If you open the JavaScript console on your browser, it will tell you about syntax errors like this. (If the browser you're using doesn't have a JavaScript console or clear errors, switch to a modern browser.)